# Quelle est la différence d'usage des termes « ailleurs », « d'ailleurs » et « par ailleurs » ?

Tags: sens, usage, choix-de-mot

J'ai trouvé ces termes dans certains textes, mais je ne sais pas quelle est la différence.

Exemples :

> D'ailleurs bientôt il serait entendu par le juge.
>
> Comment soigner son insomnie si par ailleurs il dort dans la rue ?
>
> Il y a du monde partout, je préférerais être ailleurs.

Comment: J'ai pas envie de paraphraser le [TFLi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ailleurs).

Answer (score 9):

Pour résumer le *Trésor* et *Le Bon Usage* (Grevisse, 14e ed., §1034 f):

- *Ailleurs* est un adverbe locatif qui signifie "en un autre endroit".
- *D'ailleurs* est une locution adverbiale qui signifie "en outre", "de plus", on l'emploie parfois de manière concessive.
- *Par ailleurs* signifie à peu près "d'autre part" ou "d'un autre côté", avec une nuance d'opposition.
- *Par ailleurs* et *d'ailleurs* s'emploient aussi comme simple combinaison de *par/de* avec *ailleurs* (*venu d'ailleurs, passer par ailleurs* etc.).

*Par ailleurs* me semble incorrect dans ton exemple. On dirait une espèce d'accent (d'emphase, si vous me passez l'anglicisme), sens que *par ailleurs* n'a normalement pas.

Comment: Si je ne m'abuse, *emphase* en soi n'est pas un anglicisme. Par contre, *mettre l'emphase* l'est.

Comment: Ah... J'imagine que j'ai un réflexe automatique car il y avait un chapitre entier sur ce mot dans mon manuel de traduction XD

Comment: *La traduction raisonnée*, par hasard?

Comment: @Kareen Exactement! De fait, après vérification, ce n'est pas le cas (je ne peux même pas dire si le mot y est mentionné: ce bouquin souffre d'une absence criminelle d'index!). Je ne suis plus certain où et quand durant mes quatre ans d'études pour mon bac en traduction j'ai acquis ce réflexe...

Comment: L'exemple de _par ailleurs_ me gène aussi.

Comment: Ici le *par ailleurs* (synonyme de *d'autre part*) est tout à fait justifié, car il localise un *ailleurs* (*un autre endroit* qui est la rue). L'exemple est pertinent, même s'il n'est pas d'usage courant.